# How do I align daily timeline in SSRS on single rows?

Tags: t-sql, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I'm trying to create an SSRS report where the same hour from each day aligns single row?  Below is what I have so far in my tablix, but as you will see it places separate dates (columns) on separate rows instead of the same row.  (Also I want to be able to add in one more column which would be the `BucketSort` column so I can see what time it is).  Currently this tablix structure is very simple.
[image: report_preview]

Where structure is like this:
[image: report_design]

```html
CREATE TABLE #wam(
 [date] [date] NULL,
 [BucketSort] [varchar](5) NULL,
 [DAY1] [varchar](max) NULL
) 

insert #wam values ('2019-02-12' ,'08:00', 'CALL 1')
insert #wam values ('2019-02-12' ,'08:00', 'PTO')
insert #wam values ('2019-02-12' ,'08:00', 'TIME OFF REQUEST APPROVED')
insert #wam values ('2019-02-12' ,'08:00', 'AVAILABLE')
insert #wam values ('2019-02-12' ,'09:00', 'COUNTY LINE MILEAGE')
insert #wam values ('2019-02-12' ,'16:00', 'MILEAGE FOR ATTEMPTED VISIT AND NON VISITS')
insert #wam values ('2019-02-12' ,'16:00', 'COUNTY LINE MILEAGE')
insert #wam values ('2019-02-13' ,'08:00', 'CALL 2')
insert #wam values ('2019-02-13' ,'08:00', 'AVAILABLE')
insert #wam values ('2019-02-13' ,'09:00', 'NVA Custom1')
insert #wam values ('2019-02-13' ,'16:00', 'NVA Custom2')
insert #wam values ('2019-02-13' ,'16:00', 'NVA Custom3')
insert #wam values ('2019-02-14' ,'08:00', 'PTO')
insert #wam values ('2019-02-14' ,'08:00', 'AVAILABLE')
insert #wam values ('2019-02-14' ,'09:00', 'NVA Custom4')
insert #wam values ('2019-02-14' ,'16:00', 'NVA Custom6')
insert #wam values ('2019-02-14' ,'16:00', 'NVA Custom5')
insert #wam values ('2019-02-15' ,'08:00', 'TIME OFF REQUEST APPROVED')
insert #wam values ('2019-02-15' ,'08:00', 'AVAILABLE')
insert #wam values ('2019-02-18' ,'08:00', 'AVAILABLE')
```

As you can see from above query, there can be more than one event for the same day and timeslot.

Comment: Do you want to highlight the current hour in the report?  *Also I want to be able to add in one more column which would be the `BucketSort` column so I can see what time it is*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by [nesting a tablix in a matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/nested-data-regions-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017)

#### Example Report Preview

[image: screenshot]

#### Example Report Design

[image: screenshot]

#### Here's the report XML from the .rdl file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report MustUnderstand="df" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns:df="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition/defaultfontfamily">
  <Description>A calendar view of the events</Description>
  <df:DefaultFontFamily>Segoe UI</df:DefaultFontFamily>
  <AutoRefresh>0</AutoRefresh>
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="yourdatasource">
      <DataSourceReference>yourdatasource</DataSourceReference>
      <rd:SecurityType>None</rd:SecurityType>
      <rd:DataSourceID>68eb8e17-19b1-4ab3-8315-91c1cb31c63a</rd:DataSourceID>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="Sessions">
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>yourdatasource</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText>SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
  ( 'John Doe', '12-Feb-2019', '08:00', 'CALL 1')
, ( 'John Doe', '12-Feb-2019', '08:00', 'PTO')
, ( 'John Doe', '12-Feb-2019', '08:00', 'TIME OFF REQUEST APPROVED')
, ( 'John Doe', '12-Feb-2019', '08:00', 'AVAILABLE')
, ( 'John Doe', '12-Feb-2019', '09:00', 'COUNTY LINE MILEAGE')
, ( 'John Doe', '12-Feb-2019', '16:00', 'MILEAGE FOR ATTEMPTED VISIT AND NON VISITS')
, ( 'John Doe', '12-Feb-2019', '16:00', 'COUNTY LINE MILEAGE')
, ( 'John Doe', '13-Feb-2019', '08:00', 'CALL 2')
, ( 'John Doe', '13-Feb-2019', '08:00', 'AVAILABLE')
, ( 'John Doe', '13-Feb-2019', '09:00', 'NVA Custom1')
, ( 'John Doe', '13-Feb-2019', '16:00', 'NVA Custom2')
, ( 'John Doe', '13-Feb-2019', '16:00', 'NVA Custom3')
, ( 'John Doe', '14-Feb-2019', '08:00', 'PTO')
, ( 'John Doe', '14-Feb-2019', '08:00', 'AVAILABLE')
, ( 'John Doe', '14-Feb-2019', '09:00', 'NVA Custom4')
, ( 'John Doe', '14-Feb-2019', '16:00', 'NVA Custom6')
, ( 'John Doe', '14-Feb-2019', '16:00', 'NVA Custom5')
, ( 'John Doe', '15-Feb-2019', '08:00', 'TIME OFF REQUEST APPROVED')
, ( 'John Doe', '15-Feb-2019', '08:00', 'AVAILABLE')
, ( 'John Doe', '18-Feb-2019', '08:00', 'AVAILABLE')
) tbl ([UserName], [date], [BucketSort], [DAY1]) </CommandText>
      </Query>
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="UserName">
          <DataField>UserName</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="date">
          <DataField>date</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="BucketSort">
          <DataField>BucketSort</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="DAY1">
          <DataField>DAY1</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
      </Fields>
    </DataSet>
  </DataSets>
  <ReportSections>
    <ReportSection>
      <Body>
        <ReportItems>
          <Tablix Name="tbxDynamicGroupHeader">
            <TablixBody>
              <TablixColumns>
                <TablixColumn>
                  <Width>9.65604cm</Width>
                </TablixColumn>
              </TablixColumns>
              <TablixRows>
                <TablixRow>
                  <Height>0.6cm</Height>
                  <TablixCells>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Textbox Name="lblDynamicGroupHeader">
                          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph>
                              <TextRuns>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value />
                                  <Style>
                                    <FontFamily>Tahoma</FontFamily>
                                    <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                                    <Color>DimGray</Color>
                                  </Style>
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns>
                              <Style>
                                <TextAlign>Left</TextAlign>
                              </Style>
                            </Paragraph>
                          </Paragraphs>
                          <Style>
                            <Border>
                              <Style>Solid</Style>
                              <Width>0.75pt</Width>
                            </Border>
                            <BackgroundColor>=Variables!ColorTableHeader.Value</BackgroundColor>
                            <VerticalAlign>Middle</VerticalAlign>
                          </Style>
                        </Textbox>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                  </TablixCells>
                </TablixRow>
                <TablixRow>
                  <Height>1.6675cm</Height>
                  <TablixCells>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Tablix Name="tbxBookingDetails">
                          <TablixBody>
                            <TablixColumns>
                              <TablixColumn>
                                <Width>7.12802cm</Width>
                              </TablixColumn>
                            </TablixColumns>
                            <TablixRows>
                              <TablixRow>
                                <Height>0.9175cm</Height>
                                <TablixCells>
                                  <TablixCell>
                                    <CellContents>
                                      <Textbox Name="lblday_name">
                                        <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                                        <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                                        <Paragraphs>
                                          <Paragraph>
                                            <TextRuns>
                                              <TextRun>
                                                <Value>=Fields!date.Value</Value>
                                                <Style>
                                                  <FontFamily>Tahoma</FontFamily>
                                                  <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                                                  <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                                                  <Color>DimGray</Color>
                                                </Style>
                                              </TextRun>
                                            </TextRuns>
                                            <Style>
                                              <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                                            </Style>
                                          </Paragraph>
                                        </Paragraphs>
                                        <Style>
                                          <Border>
                                            <Style>Solid</Style>
                                            <Width>0.75pt</Width>
                                          </Border>
                                          <BackgroundColor>=Variables!ColorTableHeader.Value</BackgroundColor>
                                          <VerticalAlign>Middle</VerticalAlign>
                                        </Style>
                                      </Textbox>
                                    </CellContents>
                                  </TablixCell>
                                </TablixCells>
                              </TablixRow>
                              <TablixRow>
                                <Height>0.75cm</Height>
                                <TablixCells>
                                  <TablixCell>
                                    <CellContents>
                                      <Tablix Name="tbxDay">
                                        <TablixBody>
                                          <TablixColumns>
                                            <TablixColumn>
                                              <Width>7.12802cm</Width>
                                            </TablixColumn>
                                          </TablixColumns>
                                          <TablixRows>
                                            <TablixRow>
                                              <Height>0.75cm</Height>
                                              <TablixCells>
                                                <TablixCell>
                                                  <CellContents>
                                                    <Textbox Name="txtroom_name">
                                                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                                                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                                                      <Paragraphs>
                                                        <Paragraph>
                                                          <TextRuns>
                                                            <TextRun>
                                                              <Value>=Fields!DAY1.Value</Value>
                                                              <Style>
                                                                <FontFamily>Tahoma</FontFamily>
                                                                <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                                                              </Style>
                                                            </TextRun>
                                                          </TextRuns>
                                                          <Style>
                                                            <TextAlign>Left</TextAlign>
                                                          </Style>
                                                        </Paragraph>
                                                      </Paragraphs>
                                                      <Style>
                                                        <Border>
                                                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                                                          <Style>None</Style>
                                                          <Width>0.75pt</Width>
                                                        </Border>
                                                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                                                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                                                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                                                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                                                      </Style>
                                                    </Textbox>
                                                  </CellContents>
                                                </TablixCell>
                                              </TablixCells>
                                            </TablixRow>
                                          </TablixRows>
                                        </TablixBody>
                                        <TablixColumnHierarchy>
                                          <TablixMembers>
                                            <TablixMember />
                                          </TablixMembers>
                                        </TablixColumnHierarchy>
                                        <TablixRowHierarchy>
                                          <TablixMembers>
                                            <TablixMember>
                                              <Group Name="Details" />
                                              <SortExpressions>
                                                <SortExpression>
                                                  <Value>=Fields!DAY1.Value</Value>
                                                </SortExpression>
                                              </SortExpressions>
                                              <TablixMembers>
                                                <TablixMember />
                                              </TablixMembers>
                                            </TablixMember>
                                          </TablixMembers>
                                        </TablixRowHierarchy>
                                        <DataSetName>Sessions</DataSetName>
                                        <Style>
                                          <Border>
                                            <Style>Solid</Style>
                                            <Width>0.75pt</Width>
                                          </Border>
                                          <BackgroundColor>=Code.CandyStripe(False, Variables!ColorCandyStripeOddRow.Value, Variables!ColorCandyStripeEvenRow.Value)</BackgroundColor>
                                          <FontFamily>Tahoma</FontFamily>
                                          <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                                        </Style>
                                      </Tablix>
                                    </CellContents>
                                  </TablixCell>
                                </TablixCells>
                              </TablixRow>
                            </TablixRows>
                          </TablixBody>
                          <TablixColumnHierarchy>
                            <TablixMembers>
                              <TablixMember>
                                <Group Name="ColumnGroup">
                                  <GroupExpressions>
                                    <GroupExpression>=Fields!date.Value</GroupExpression>
                                  </GroupExpressions>
                                </Group>
                                <SortExpressions>
                                  <SortExpression>
                                    <Value>=Fields!date.Value</Value>
                                  </SortExpression>
                                </SortExpressions>
                                <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                              </TablixMember>
                            </TablixMembers>
                          </TablixColumnHierarchy>
                          <TablixRowHierarchy>
                            <TablixMembers>
                              <TablixMember>
                                <TablixHeader>
                                  <Size>2.52802cm</Size>
                                  <CellContents>
                                    <Textbox Name="lblweek_date">
                                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                                      <Paragraphs>
                                        <Paragraph>
                                          <TextRuns>
                                            <TextRun>
                                              <Value>Time</Value>
                                              <Style>
                                                <FontFamily>Tahoma</FontFamily>
                                                <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                                                <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                                                <Color>DimGray</Color>
                                              </Style>
                                            </TextRun>
                                          </TextRuns>
                                          <Style>
                                            <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                                          </Style>
                                        </Paragraph>
                                      </Paragraphs>
                                      <Style>
                                        <Border>
                                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                                          <Width>0.75pt</Width>
                                        </Border>
                                        <BackgroundColor>=Variables!ColorTableHeader.Value</BackgroundColor>
                                        <VerticalAlign>Middle</VerticalAlign>
                                      </Style>
                                    </Textbox>
                                  </CellContents>
                                </TablixHeader>
                                <TablixMembers>
                                  <TablixMember>
                                    <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                                  </TablixMember>
                                </TablixMembers>
                                <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>
                                <RepeatOnNewPage>true</RepeatOnNewPage>
                                <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                              </TablixMember>
                              <TablixMember>
                                <Group Name="week_date">
                                  <GroupExpressions>
                                    <GroupExpression>=Fields!BucketSort.Value</GroupExpression>
                                  </GroupExpressions>
                                </Group>
                                <SortExpressions>
                                  <SortExpression>
                                    <Value>=Fields!BucketSort.Value</Value>
                                  </SortExpression>
                                </SortExpressions>
                                <TablixHeader>
                                  <Size>2.52802cm</Size>
                                  <CellContents>
                                    <Textbox Name="txtweek_date">
                                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                                      <Paragraphs>
                                        <Paragraph>
                                          <TextRuns>
                                            <TextRun>
                                              <Value>=Fields!BucketSort.Value</Value>
                                              <Style>
                                                <FontFamily>Tahoma</FontFamily>
                                                <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                                                <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                                                <Format>=Variables!FormatDate.Value</Format>
                                              </Style>
                                            </TextRun>
                                          </TextRuns>
                                          <Style>
                                            <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                                          </Style>
                                        </Paragraph>
                                      </Paragraphs>
                                      <Style>
                                        <Border>
                                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                                          <Width>0.75pt</Width>
                                        </Border>
                                        <BackgroundColor>=Code.CandyStripe(True, Variables!ColorCandyStripeEvenRow.Value, Variables!ColorCandyStripeOddRow.Value)</BackgroundColor>
                                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                                      </Style>
                                    </Textbox>
                                  </CellContents>
                                </TablixHeader>
                                <TablixMembers>
                                  <TablixMember>
                                    <RepeatOnNewPage>true</RepeatOnNewPage>
                                    <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                                  </TablixMember>
                                </TablixMembers>
                                <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                              </TablixMember>
                            </TablixMembers>
                          </TablixRowHierarchy>
                          <RepeatRowHeaders>true</RepeatRowHeaders>
                          <DataSetName>Sessions</DataSetName>
                          <Style>
                            <Border>
                              <Style>None</Style>
                              <Width>0.75pt</Width>
                            </Border>
                            <FontFamily>Tahoma</FontFamily>
                          </Style>
                        </Tablix>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                  </TablixCells>
                </TablixRow>
              </TablixRows>
            </TablixBody>
            <TablixColumnHierarchy>
              <TablixMembers>
                <TablixMember />
              </TablixMembers>
            </TablixColumnHierarchy>
            <TablixRowHierarchy>
              <TablixMembers>
                <TablixMember>
                  <Group Name="grpDocumentMap">
                    <GroupExpressions>
                      <GroupExpression>=Fields!UserName.Value</GroupExpression>
                    </GroupExpressions>
                    <PageBreak>
                      <BreakLocation>Between</BreakLocation>
                    </PageBreak>
                  </Group>
                  <SortExpressions>
                    <SortExpression>
                      <Value>=Fields!UserName.Value</Value>
                    </SortExpression>
                  </SortExpressions>
                  <TablixMembers>
                    <TablixMember />
                    <TablixMember />
                  </TablixMembers>
                </TablixMember>
              </TablixMembers>
            </TablixRowHierarchy>
            <RepeatColumnHeaders>true</RepeatColumnHeaders>
            <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
            <DataSetName>Sessions</DataSetName>
            <Height>2.2675cm</Height>
            <Width>9.65604cm</Width>
            <Style>
              <Border>
                <Style>None</Style>
              </Border>
            </Style>
          </Tablix>
        </ReportItems>
        <Height>0.89272in</Height>
        <Style />
      </Body>
      <Width>3.80159in</Width>
      <Page>
        <PageFooter>
          <Height>0.02646cm</Height>
          <PrintOnFirstPage>true</PrintOnFirstPage>
          <PrintOnLastPage>true</PrintOnLastPage>
          <Style>
            <Border>
              <Style>None</Style>
            </Border>
          </Style>
        </PageFooter>
        <PageHeight>29.7cm</PageHeight>
        <PageWidth>42cm</PageWidth>
        <LeftMargin>0.5cm</LeftMargin>
        <RightMargin>0.5cm</RightMargin>
        <TopMargin>1cm</TopMargin>
        <BottomMargin>1cm</BottomMargin>
        <ColumnSpacing>0.13cm</ColumnSpacing>
        <Style>
          <Border>
            <Style>None</Style>
          </Border>
          <BottomBorder>
            <Style>Solid</Style>
          </BottomBorder>
        </Style>
      </Page>
    </ReportSection>
  </ReportSections>
  <ReportParametersLayout>
    <GridLayoutDefinition>
      <NumberOfColumns>3</NumberOfColumns>
      <NumberOfRows>2</NumberOfRows>
    </GridLayoutDefinition>
  </ReportParametersLayout>
  <Code>
        Private Alt As Boolean

        Public Function CandyStripe(ByVal NewRow As Boolean, ByVal OddColor as String, ByVal EvenColor as String) As String
        '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ' Purpose:  To candy stripe the detail rows of a report
        ' Example:  BackgroundColor = Code.CandyStripe()
        ' Note:     The first column needs a parameter of "True" passed in example: Code.CandyStripe(True)
        '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        If NewRow Then
        Alt = Not Alt
        End If

        If Alt Then
        Return OddColor
        Else
        Return EvenColor
        End If

        End Function
    </Code>
  <Variables>
    <Variable Name="ColorCandyStripeEvenRow">
      <Value>#FFFFFF</Value>
    </Variable>
    <Variable Name="ColorCandyStripeOddRow">
      <Value>WhiteSmoke</Value>
    </Variable>
    <Variable Name="ColorTableHeader">
      <Value>WhiteSmoke</Value>
    </Variable>
    <Variable Name="FormatDate">
      <Value>dd-MMM-yyyy</Value>
    </Variable>
    <Variable Name="FormatDateTime">
      <Value>dd-MMM-yyyy  hh:mm tt</Value>
    </Variable>
    <Variable Name="UserName">
      <Value>=Right(User!UserID, len(User!UserID)-instr(User!UserID, "\"))</Value>
    </Variable>
  </Variables>
  <rd:ReportUnitType>Cm</rd:ReportUnitType>
  <rd:ReportID>6203a576-d7cc-4b57-9a9b-12cf325d6203</rd:ReportID>
</Report>
```